# svn not found with sudo in front of it

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, subversion

when I want to start `svn` with `sudo`, I get this error message

```
sudo: svn: command not found
```

I recently compiled the newest subversion on my own and removed the `subversion` from my RedHat 7 machine. When I log as a user on my system and type `svn`, I get `Type 'svn help' for usage.`, which indicates, that is could find `svn`.

According to https://serverfault.com/a/505972/297310 I started to investigate where the problem might be.

First, I checked my `$PATH` variable

```
echo $PATH
> /usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/gradle/latest/bin:/root/bin
sudo echo $PATH
> /usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/gradle/latest/bin:/root/bin
```

No difference in output, when call these commands as user or root.

```
whereis svn
> svn: /usr/local/bin/svn
sudo whereis svn
> svn: /usr/local/bin/svn
```

The same as with `$PATH`. This is somehow odd. When I type these commands, this does not help

```
svn
> Type 'svn help' for usage.
sudo svn
> sudo: svn: command not found
```

Can anyone give me some hints, how to find the solution. I do not want to install the `subversion` package again, because I want to use the latest subversion and the package version is to old for my purposes.

Comment: `sudo` does not preserve your environment for security reasons, especially not `$PATH`. If you are allowed to, you may try `sudo -E svn` (see `man sudo`). For the default $PATH and default kept environments see `sudo -l`.

Comment: If you issue `sudo echo $PATH`then $PATH will be resolved by the calling shell, not the `sudo`shell. And `whereis`does not only look in `$PATH` and `$MANPATH`, but also in some hardcoded places (try `whereis -l` to see the whole tree). If instead you use `which`command, you will see the difference. Or `sudo su` and the `echo $PATH`.